# Python: Use mouse to draw a rectangle around objects in any window? Also store start and end coordinates as variables relative to said window?

Tags: python, user-interface, input, mouse, store

I'm very new to Python and need an approach for accomplishing an important function I've done before in macro-scripting languages:

I have a Python program that will be processing a screengrab image using pyscreenshot.  In order to feed pyscreenshot the necessary x1, y1, x2, y2 coordinates to create the image, I need the user to define the portion of the screen by drawing a rectangle around it.  Think "snipping" tool in Windows and cmd+shift+4 in OSX.

I am open to using any BSD module necessary but I need module support for OSX and Windows.

Every example I've found is for how to draw a rectangle within a canvas or on an existing image file.  These examples don't help me because I need the coordinates to be drawn-over and relative to any OS window the user chooses.

Thanks so much for the help!!!

Looked at tutorials to draw rectangles in opencv, pyautogui, tkinter but all drew the rectangles over a window or canvas drawn by the program, not the OS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would first grab a screenshot of your current desktop, display it in a `Canvas`, and let your user to draw a rectangle on it. Then retrieve the bounding box of the rectangle and perform an actual grab on the desktop. Below is a basic sample (drag to create an image):

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageGrab, ImageTk

class GUI(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.withdraw()
        self.attributes('-fullscreen', True)

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self)
        self.canvas.pack(fill="both",expand=True)

        image = ImageGrab.grab()
        self.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
        self.photo = self.canvas.create_image(0,0,image=self.image,anchor="nw")

        self.x, self.y = 0, 0
        self.rect, self.start_x, self.start_y = None, None, None
        self.deiconify()

        self.canvas.tag_bind(self.photo,"<ButtonPress-1>", self.on_button_press)
        self.canvas.tag_bind(self.photo,"<B1-Motion>", self.on_move_press)
        self.canvas.tag_bind(self.photo,"<ButtonRelease-1>", self.on_button_release)

    def on_button_press(self, event):
        self.start_x = event.x
        self.start_y = event.y
        self.rect = self.canvas.create_rectangle(self.x, self.y, 1, 1, outline='red')

    def on_move_press(self, event):
        curX, curY = (event.x, event.y)
        self.canvas.coords(self.rect, self.start_x, self.start_y, curX, curY)

    def on_button_release(self, event):
        bbox = self.canvas.bbox(self.rect)
        self.withdraw()
        self.new_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(ImageGrab.grab(bbox))
        self.attributes('-fullscreen', False)
        self.title("Image grabbed")
        self.canvas.destroy()
        self.deiconify()
        tk.Label(self,image=self.new_image).pack()

root = GUI()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, Henry Yik!  I will try this out, I am on mobile right now.  However, am I understanding correctly that this method will give me coordinates relative to the entire screen?  I need coordinates relative to a smaller window, chosen by the user, which may move around the screen depending on their workflow.

Comment: It’s not possible to directly draw on your desktop, so the current approach is one way to simulate it. Does it help to achieve what you want?

Comment: Henry Yik, I tried your code and it is very cool.  It works exactly like snipping tool and ctrl+shift+4 which is awesome!  However, that was my mistake when describing my needs.  I don't need to perform the same action as those other tools, I just need the functionality they have to draw the box visually over the screen (as you've simulated perfectly in this code).

My true goal is to define an area relative to a window which I will use the coordinates of to create screengrabs at certain intervals in my code.  Visually, what you've created here works exactly how I need it too.

Comment: The problem is, I'm worried that this method will assign the coordinates relative to the canvas, not the user's selected mini-window.  

I love the way your tool works very much.  Is there another function I could combine parts of it with that will read coordinates relative to a specific window on the screen?  If so, will opening the canvas window cause the canvas to be the selected window, therefore negating the user's chosen window?  Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Hmm can't say I fully understand, but let's just explain a bit more on the logic. Currently, the tkinter window will first hide itself, and then attempt to grab a screenshot of your desktop and then reappear to display it as full size. After you create the rectangle, it will hide again and grab the desktop using the bbox of the rectangle - which is relative to both the canvas and your desktop. If you have chosen the area correctly, it should not have any problem selecting your mini-window.

Comment: Yes, visually, what you're saying is true.  The problem is, I don't actually want to manually make any screen-caps.  That will be done later using the rectangle's coordinates as a "capture area".  The box only serves visually to help the user see the selected area whilie their click and release are simultaneously defining the capture area coordinates.

Those coordinates need to be measured relative to the small window they're currently on, not the full screen.  If the canvas is the size of the whole screen and is the frontmost window, how will that work?  Thanks again so much!!!